# Custom post type single page (single-{CPT-name}) 404 when slug includes hyphens

Tags: custom-post-types, 404-error, slug

I have a CPT called "author". After an hour searching why I get a 404 visiting single pages of this CPT (managed by template "single-author.php") I realize that *some* do work: those whose slug doesn't include an hyphen !

So for author "Voltaire", my_site.com/author/voltaire/ works. However for "Alexandre Dumas", my_site.com/author/alexandre-dumas/ gives a 404. If I change this slug from "alexandre-dumas" into "alexandredumas" without hyphen, it works.

I need to use hyphens in my author slugs (otherwise I'd need to ask my client to manually edit the slug of every single author she creates or created), how to do that?

My CPT declaration:

```
function my_custom_post_author() {
    $labels = array(
        'name'               => _x( 'Book Authors', 'post type general name' ),
        'singular_name'      => _x( 'Book Author', 'post type singular name' ),
        'add_new'            => _x( 'Add New', 'book author' ),
        'add_new_item'       => __( 'Add New Book Author' ),
        'edit_item'          => __( 'Edit Book Author' ),
        'new_item'           => __( 'New Book Author' ),
        'all_items'          => __( 'All Book Author' ),
        'view_item'          => __( 'View Book Author' ),
        'search_items'       => __( 'Search Book Author' ),
        'not_found'          => __( 'No book authors found' ),
        'not_found_in_trash' => __( 'No book authors found in the Trash' ), 
        'parent_item_colon'  => '',
        'menu_name'          => 'Book Authors'
    );
    $args = array(
        'labels'        => $labels,
        'description'   => 'Holds our authors specific data',
        'public'        => true,
        'menu_position' => 4,
        'supports'      => array( 'title', 'editor', 'thumbnail', 'excerpt', 'comments', 'custom-fields'),
        'rewrite' => array( 'slug' => 'book-author','with_front' => FALSE),
        'has_archive'   => true,
    );
    register_post_type( 'book-author', $args );     
}
add_action( 'init', 'my_custom_post_author' );

function my_updated_messages_author( $messages ) {
    global $post, $post_ID;
    $messages['book-author'] = array(
        0 => '', 
        1 => sprintf( __('Book Author updated. <a href="%s">View book author</a>'), esc_url( get_permalink($post_ID) ) ),
        2 => __('Custom field updated.'),
        3 => __('Custom field deleted.'),
        4 => __('Book author updated.'),
        5 => isset($_GET['revision']) ? sprintf( __('Book author restored to revision from %s'), wp_post_revision_title( (int) $_GET['revision'], false ) ) : false,
        6 => sprintf( __('Book author published. <a href="%s">View book author</a>'), esc_url( get_permalink($post_ID) ) ),
        7 => __('Book author saved.'),
        8 => sprintf( __('Book author submitted. <a target="_blank" href="%s">Preview book author</a>'), esc_url( add_query_arg( 'preview', 'true', get_permalink($post_ID) ) ) ),
        9 => sprintf( __('Book author scheduled for: <strong>%1$s</strong>. <a target="_blank" href="%2$s">Preview book author</a>'), date_i18n( __( 'M j, Y @ G:i' ), strtotime( $post->post_date ) ), esc_url( get_permalink($post_ID) ) ),
        10 => sprintf( __('Book author draft updated. <a target="_blank" href="%s">Preview book author</a>'), esc_url( add_query_arg( 'preview', 'true', get_permalink($post_ID) ) ) ),
    );
    return $messages;
}
add_filter( 'post_updated_messages', 'my_updated_messages_author' );
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Without testing, I'll guess this has nothing to do with the author names specifically, but the fact that `author` is a built in WordPress query var, and `/author/author-name/` is the default permalink for author archives. Change your post type name so the query var no longer clashes, then either change your post type rewrite slug, or change the the default slug for author archives in the init action:

```
global $wp_rewrite;
$wp_rewrite->author_base = 'blog-author';
```

Comment: Changed CPT name and also slug to "book-author", no problem now !

Comment: I had to recreate all my "author" posts though, within my new "book-author" CPT. Is there a way to somehow migrate the posts from previous CPT (author) to new one (book-author) ?

Comment: there are plugins that can possibly help, or if you have phpMyAdmin, you just need to update the `post_type` column for each post and change the name of the post type, or via a SQL query, like : `UPDATE wp_posts SET post_type='book-author' WHERE post_type='author'`